# Angular 6 SSR error while - !window.ace is not defined. How make a SSR wrapper for Ace editor?

Tags: angular6, ace-editor, server-side-rendering

Can't start SSR with Ace editor on Angular 6. I'm afraid that there I need some wrapper for SSR, but in Ace lib which used by AceEditorModule already exist some conditions for existing the window.ace or not, but it not work properly.

- "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.3.8"
- Angular 6.0.7

any ideas how to fix this?

```
npm run start:ssr

> my-project@0.0.0 start:ssr I:\FRONTEND\Projects\Github\my-project - UNEXPECTED ERRORS
> node dist/server.js

I:\FRONTEND\Projects\Github\my-project - UNEXPECTED ERRORS\dist\server.js:254298
                    if (!window.ace)
                    ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at I:\FRONTEND\Projects\Github\my-project - UNEXPECTED ERRORS\dist\server.js:254298:21
    at _acequire (I:\FRONTEND\Projects\Github\my-project - UNEXPECTED ERRORS\dist\server.js:235317:37)
    at Object.acequire (I:\FRONTEND\Projects\Github\my-project - UNEXPECTED ERRORS\dist\server.js:235322:26)
```

---

IIFE which produce this error and try to handle window object with ace lib inside: `node_modules/ace-builds/src/ace.js`

```
(function() {
  window.require(["ace/ace"], function(a) {
    if (a) {
      a.config.init(true);
      a.define = window.define;
    }
    if (!window.ace)
      window.ace = a;
      for (var key in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(key))
        window.ace[key] = a[key];
        window.ace["default"] = window.ace;
        if (typeof module == "object" && typeof exports == "object" && module){
          module.exports = window.ace;
        }
     });
})();
```

also npm package use `brace` as dependency, and in it also we see this code, but its different a little bit. And I don't know how to check which of lib's code produce this error.
`node_modules/brace/index.js`:

```
(function() {
                ace.acequire(["ace/ace"], function(a) {
                    if (a) {
                        a.config.init(true);
                        a.define = ace.define;
                    }
                    if (!window.ace)
                        window.ace = a;
                    for (var key in a) if (a.hasOwnProperty(key))
                        window.ace[key] = a[key];
                });
            })();
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
 if (typeof window == "undefined")
     global.window = global
```

Comment: where? In polyfills.ts already exist and not work unfortunately

Comment: do this before the first require call for ace or the module using ace (brace/ng2-ace-editor)

Answer (score 0):

Add module to tsconfig.server.json !!

[image]